# $\mu$-recursive definitions for the complexity classes P, NP, etc

Tags: computability-theory, computational-complexity

The standard complexity classes such as P, NP are usually defined using Turing Machines. In finite model theory those classes can be defined via the classical first-order/second-order logics.

I am curious whether there exists an equivalent definition of such classes via $\mu$-recursive functions. What about register machines? lambda calculus? etc? In computability theory it is known that $\mu$-recursive functions, counter machines, lambda calculus and Turing Machines are all equivalent. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function)

Comment: You can define PTIME using first-order logic? FO characterises LOGSPACE. For PTIME there is no such characterisation, only LFP on ordered structures.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Actually I have in mind in general finite model theory characterises complexity classes via FO/MSO/Fixed-point. I don't don't really mean P,NP. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: I mean, actually it is unknown whether there is such a characterisation for PTIME, thus you would be famous if you could. ;) And I am sorry, FO is weaker than LOGSPACE, that was my point.

Comment: It is true. Thanks anyway for the answer... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. See [Cob64]. 
The idea is to replace primitive recursion 
in the definition of primitive recursive functions with bounded recursion on notion.

Another more delicate approach is taken in [BC92].

- Alan Cobham, "[The Intrinsic Computational Difficulty of Functions](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2003.10.017)", 1964
- Stephen Bellantoni and Stephen A. Cook, "[A New Recursion Theoretic Characterization of The Polytime Functions](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~sacook/homepage/ptime.pdf)", 1992